# Getting column is of type jsonb[] but expression is of type text[] when trying to insert with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using `execute_values` to insert the content of many tables on other tables, I already set the adapter of `dict` to `json` when I received other error, however I don't know how to treat this one:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "rules" is of type jsonb[] but expression is of type text[]
>           LINE 1: ...UES (1,'tturxvrtgvvsrqgzsedcoyqujakyepjordrbbjdw',ARRAY['{"i...

The only way to handle that was something like [this issue](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/585), but I would need to treat each column ...

Maybe there are ways to create a new adapter, but I couldn't achieve how to do that by the docs.

```py
register_adapter(dict, Json)

execute_values(
            dest_cursor,
            f'''
            INSERT INTO {t} VALUES %s ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
            ''',
            records,
    )
```

Is there a automatic way to deal with that, like the `register_adapter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer by [this issue](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/911#issuecomment-488699987) I learned I could use the `template` parameter, like so:

```py
execute_values(
  dest_cursor,
  f'''
  INSERT INTO {t} VALUES %s ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
  ''',
  records,
  template="(%s, %s, %s::jsonb[], %s, %s)" # as many placeholders requested
)
```